# React Js component or way to display both html and emoj

Tags: reactjs

I want to display text which can contain with **emoj** and **html** . I`ve already using [react-emoji-render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-emoji-render) component. But it's not supporting **HTML** .

Example text I want to display:

`<h1>Hello</h1> :)`

Comment: Check this once made a demo on react-easy-emoji , might this can help you https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qq91ig

Answer (score 0):

Will this help (instead of using `react-emoji-render`)?:

```
1. Include <link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet"> to html template.
2. Use it: <h1>Hello world! <i class="em-svg em-100"></i></h1>
```

[Library](https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I need to identify :D also as emoji , currently react-emoji-render  doing that. But its problem , Its not supporting HTML tags.